# How to access Apache Tomcat in Window 7

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have installed the Apache Tomcat in Windows 7 PC and I need to access from the network PC. But in getting below error message

```
Description: Unable to locate the server named "hostname" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.
```

Comment: Tried the ip-address of your WIndows 7 PC for connection ? Depending on the size of your network you might also have to add the domain: hostname.my.company

Comment: I tried till I am getting same error message. Whether I need to configure anything in firewall??

Comment: No, I don't think that this is caused by a firewall. Please create a screenshot (gyazo.com might be of use here) what happens when you try to connect with your browser.